# a code which reverses null terminated string

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, stack

- I am new to js.
- I am trying to write a code which reverses null terminated string.
- I tried writing using push and pop.
- but i am not getting output, can you tell me what is the problem.
- providing code below

```or-tag-here
var word = "Cell0";
//var char = word.stringCharAT();


for (i=0;  i< word.length; i++) {
    var pushWord = [];

    pushWord.push(word[i]);

    for (j=0;  j< pushWord.length; j++) {
        var reverseWord= [];
        reverseWord = pushWord[j].pop;
        console.log("reverseWord" + reverseWord);

    } 
}
```

Comment: `pushWord[j]` is not an array, `.pop` is not called. What is expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.

```
var word = "Cell0"; 
var reversed = ''; 
for (var i = word.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversed += word[i];
} 
console.log(reversed);
```

This loops through the characters of the string in reverse and adds the characters to a new string.

Comment: hello but how to test for null terminated string

Answer (score 0):

`pushWord[j]` is not an array, `.pop` is not called.

Define `pushWord` and `reverseWord` arrays outside of `for` loop, within loop, after `word[i]` is pushed to `pushWord`, call `.unshift()` on `reverseWord` with `pushWord[pushWord.length -1]` as parameter.

```js
var word = "Cell0";
var pushWord = [];
var reverseWord = [];
for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  pushWord.push(word[i]);
  reverseWord.unshift(pushWord[pushWord.length - 1]);
}
console.log("reverseWord" + reverseWord);
```

Comment: hello but how to test for null terminated string

Comment: Are you trying to check for `0` character?

Comment: even i am not sure what does null terminated string means

Comment: hello can you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600110/minimise-the-code-since-i-am-using-the-same-code-only-the-content-in-p-tags-chan

Answer (score 0):

```js
var originalWord = "Cell0";
var reverseWord = [];
for (let i = 0; i < originalWord.length; i++) {
  reverseWord.unshift(originalWord [i]);
}
console.log(reverseWord.join(''));
```

You don't even need to push.
Another way to achieve the result!

Comment: hello but how to test for null terminated string

Comment: What exactly you want to test? Can you provide a test case?

Comment: In Javascript you don't need to care about null terminated string. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603931/why-doesnt-the-null-terminator-placed-arbitrarily-in-a-string-terminate-it

Comment: hello can you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600110/minimise-the-code-since-i-am-using-the-same-code-only-the-content-in-p-tags-chan

Comment: Didn't my solution help?